# Can python class run some code in parallel?

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing

The situation is there is a main.py and 2 other file A.py and B.py Each of A.py & B.py have only 1 single class and main.py calls A.py first it returns some value to main.py and then main.py calls B.py and then it returns some value to main.py and then again to A.py and so on.

What i want is to do some computation in xyz.py while main.py has called zyx.py! Is it possible? Can yield or generator function help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using "Threading".
This way you will be able to open 2 threads one for each file/method/class.

For an example take a look at this blog:
http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/simplistic-python-thread-example/

Comment: Yes your answer is correct but threading or making system calls is forbidden :(

Comment: @ZooOoz can you use Multiprocessing instead? if so please see example of multiprocessing here: 
[link](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html)